# image() function in Processing

Tags: image-processing, processing, image-resizing

So, I'm trying to crop and show a picture, and I want the picture shown to be as large as the screen each time, and so far I have this piece of code, but the image size changes each time, and according to the API it should be full screen?

```
PImage img;
PImage temp;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  img = loadImage("genevieve-bjargardottir1.jpg");
  frameRate(5);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  text(frameRate, 10, 20);

  int x, y, xx, yy;
  x = (int)random(width);
  xx = (int)random(width);
  y = (int)random(height);
  yy = (int)random(height);

  temp = img.get(x, y, xx, yy);

  image(temp, 0, 0, width, height);

}
```

I thought that the last line:

```
image(temp, 0, 0, width, height);
```

would display my cropped image to the whole window. Starting points are set to 0 0, and end points to width and height of the current window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reading @Kevin Workman's advice I came up with the following snippet :)

```java
PImage img;
PImage temp;
float prop;

void setup() {  
  while ( img == null) {
    img = loadImage("http://xaxor.com/images/Genevieve-Bjargardottir/Genevieve-Bjargardottir1.jpg");
  }

  prop =  (float)img.width / (float)img.height ;

  size(800, int(800/prop));

  frameRate(1);
}


void draw() {

  float pw = random(img.width);
  float ph = pw / prop;


  int x, y;
  x = int(random(img.width - pw));
  y = int(random(img.height - ph));

  // scaled piece
  temp = img.get(x, y, int(pw), int(ph));
  image(temp, 0, 0, width, height);

  //full pict
  image(img, 0, 0, img.width/6, img.height/6);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);

  //croped piece
  rect(x/6, y/6, pw/6, ph/6);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, good looking out v.k., thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a random part of the image each frame (5 times a second), and then displaying *that part of the image* the full size of the window. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected that the part I got would be displayed on the whole screen, but that does not happen

Comment: You aren't using a full-screen window. You're using a window that's 800x600. The width and height variables will give you the size of the window, not the size of the screen.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant the window, I want the image to be displayed in the whole window.

Comment: It is. Rather, the *random part of the image* that you're generating is. If you want the whole image displayed, why are you getting a random subsection of it?

Comment: That's what I want to do though. Get a random subsection of the image, then display <i>that</i> subsection stretched out to the whole window.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with your approach. First, you're getting a random x and y from the screen width and height. Unless your screen is the same size as the original image, that won't work. You have to reference the original image size. Then, you get a random width and height, again based off the screen size. You need to base it off of the original image size, and you need to base the width and height off of the random x and y you select: you can't select an x of 750 and a width of 750 if your image is only 800 pixels wide to start with.